# How do you abort an emacs M-x compile compilation

Tags: bash, compilation-mode, compile-mode

How do you abort an emacs M-x compile compilation?
I'm editing a bash file, and I "test execute it" by doing
M-x compile.

What I tried - googled:emacs abort compilation

The file I'm working on is like this

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                      
# -*- compile-command: "./spawn.sh" -*-                                                                          
set -e
# Function definitions 
# more ....
```

Comment: Your question title mentions `M-x compile` but your question itself says nothing about using that.

Answer (score 4):

Know that you can use `M-x compile` to compile from within Emacs.

If you do that then, in your compilation output buffer, use `C-h m` to see information about the mode.

For example, it might tell you that the mode is `compilation-mode` and that `C-c C-k` is bound to command `kill-compilation`.  Clicking that command name tells you:

```
Kill the process made by the M-x compile or M-x grep commands.
```

Similarly, if you are in `compilation-minor-mode`, where you learn that `kill-compilation` is bound to `K`, as well as to `C-c C-k`.

If you use library [`help-fns+.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/help-fns%2b.el) then you can use `C-h M-k` followed by a keymap name (e.g. `compilation-mode-map` or `compilation-minor-mode-map`), to see all of the keys bound by that keymap.

So at least if you launch your compilation from within Emacs you can kill it using `K` or `C-c C-k`.